# ExoPlayer calls onPlayerError method in EventListener after changing video quality

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I use `Exoplayer` library in my android app for playing some live HLS videos (`.m3u8` format). The version is `2.8.4`. I need to make functional in which the user can change video quality of live stream during watching it.

For this I use the followng method (I took it from `exoplayer` example project):

```
Pair<AlertDialog, TrackSelectionView> dialogPair = TrackSelectionView.getDialog(this, title, trackSelector, rendererIndex);
    dialogPair.second.setShowDisableOption(true);
    dialogPair.second.setAllowAdaptiveSelections(allowAdaptiveSelections);
    dialogPair.first.show();
```

When I select some video quality, I see that new quality, but often (sometimes very often) after few seconds exoplayer throws an error in `Player.EventListener` in `onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error)` method. ExoPlaybackException always has TYPE_SOURCE and null messages. And I also noticed, when I see live videos in auto quality, it doesnt change quality to low when my internet connection goes down, I see the same exoplayer error with TYPE_SOURCE.

Here is my code for initializing player:

```
    bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
            new DefaultRenderersFactory(getActivity()),
            trackSelector,
            new DefaultLoadControl());
    exoPlayerOnline.setPlayer(player);
    MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoStreamUrl));  
    player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
```

and method `buildMediaSource()`:

```
private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
        DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent,
                bandwidthMeter,
                20 * 1000,
                20 * 1000,
                true);
        DefaultDataSourceFactory defaultDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getActivity(),
                bandwidthMeter,
                httpDataSourceFactory);
        OkHttpDataSourceFactory okHttpDataSourceFactory = new OkHttpDataSourceFactory(okHttpClient,
                userAgent,
                bandwidthMeter);

    int type = Util.inferContentType(uri);
    switch (type) {
        case C.TYPE_SS:
            return new SsMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultSsChunkSource.Factory(defaultDataSourceFactory), okHttpDataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(uri);
        case C.TYPE_DASH:
            return new DashMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(defaultDataSourceFactory), okHttpDataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(uri);
        case C.TYPE_HLS:
            return new HlsMediaSource.Factory(okHttpDataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(uri);
        case C.TYPE_OTHER:
            return new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(okHttpDataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(uri);
        default:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unsupported video type", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
    }
}
```

So, help me please, how to solve this problem?

Comment: GOOD QUESTION. You can also ask your question in it's issue page. I think you'll get your answer quicker :)

Comment: did you find your answer ? I need some help as well